# In Design is not allowing me to place a document

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have two files in my directory that contain exactly the same XML content. One is selectable in the Place dialog and the other is not. What's going on?

Is there something I can do to allow In Design to import this document?

[image]

At one point the first file had different XML in it. I've copied and pasted the XML from the one that worked into the first file to see if the content was the cause. Look at the file size. But as you can see, it is still grayed out.

**Note:** Using InDesign CS5.5

**Update:** If I use Flash Builder 4.7 to create the new XML file it doesn't recognize it every time. I've looked at the file properties and tried different encodings and all the read write permissions. If I change the file extension to "idms" InDesign recognizes it and loads it successfully. I may add and mark changing the file extension as the solution but if I have to change the extension I lose XML syntax highlighting in the FB editor.

Comment: I don't know why the one that works works and the one that doesn't work doesn't work so I copied the one that works and then replaced it's contents with the content of the one that doesn't work and it worked. Still would like to know what is going on and why.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is this the wrong place to ask? If there is something I can improve about this question please make a comment. Otherwise leave the question alone. Someone will encounter this same situation some day and find this post. They may find out why it happens and answer it, helping the next person with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files created with Flash Builder consistently do not work when the extension is xml. Change the file extension to ".idms" instead of ".xml" *or* use a different program to create the xml file and InDesign will load it successfully.